# Office add-in: create a loading overlay over the entire word host application

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

The FluentUI got some progress loading components but they can only be applied to the add-in (which is a web application) only.

Is there anyway to display a loading overlay over the entire word host application as opposed to displaying on the add-in only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web add-ins are still very limited in UI customizations. The best what you could do is to create a popup window using [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui). Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.